# Canada immigration round of invitations

Tags: immigration, canada

Canada used to have at least 2 rounds of invitations every month. except for June this year, till today there is no invitation.

Anyone know when is the next round of invitations, or why its been delayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to have been running to end on [July 12, 2017](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/mi/index.asp#mi-pr-express).

It's probably wise to keep an eye on that page for further updates and invitations to apply.

[This page lists all previous invitation dates](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/mi/ita.asp) that have occurred, which might give you an idea of when they happen

Comment: any idea when is the next one? how many ITAs?